Is there a way to Indirectly call an array of Table names?
I am trying to find a way to dynamically merge several Tables in Excel.
eg. the tables are called Tbl_s1, Tbl_s2,... Tbl_sN.
These table names are stored in another Table called Tbl_Ref.
I was hoping to be able to call them all and stack them using:
=VSTACK(INDIRECT(INDEX(Tbl_Ref[Ref],,)))

This only results in a spill of 'N' #VALUE errors.
Does anybody have a suggestion for how I can get around this error?

Use REDUCE:
=DROP(REDUCE("",Tbl_Ref[Ref],LAMBDA(z,y,VSTACK(z,INDIRECT(y)))),1)

REDUCE will iterate each reference and vstack it one at a time then return the final result.


This works brilliant thank you! would you mind briefly explaining why it works for me?

INDEX(Tbl_Ref[Ref],,) returns an array and INDIRECT expects single value; so for example =VSTACK(INDIRECT(INDEX(Tbl_Ref[Ref],1,1)), INDIRECT(INDEX(Tbl_Ref[Ref],2,1))) would work fine. But as you can see, stacking is easier with REDUCE or SCAN.
